# How to display parsed JSON text

Tags: python, json, tkinter

Let me start off by saying that I'm starting this project to get familiar with Python.  The project is to parse JSON from Reddit.com every 15 minutes and then display it with Tkinter.

Parsing the JSON text wasn't too difficult, but I'm not sure how display the text.  I will need to display two things -- the title of the link and the link -- in a column style view.  I was also planning on having two columns side by side to take advantage of the horizontal screen width.  I've tried starting out with a Listbox, but that seemed to more be used if you want a selectable list.  I just want to display the text and be done with it.  Is there a different and more appropriate widget I should be using?  I looked into the Entry widget a bit and thought that might be getting closer, but that seemed to only be for storing a single entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a sufficiently modern version of python (2.7, 3....something, I forget) you can use the [ttk.Treeview](http://tkdocs.com/tutorial/tree.html) widget which is similar to the listbox but supports multiple columns.

A much simpler choice is to use the text widget. You can insert the text followed by a newline. To line thimgs up in columns just insert a tab, and define an appropriate tab stop.

There are plenty of other options, but those two are arguably the best.

If you haven't dicovered it yet, [tkdocs.com](http://Tkdocs.com) has a wealth of information about tkinter.

Comment: Do you know if you can put images in a TreeView?  I think this is the best solution and might try to incorporate images in other ways if it doesn't.

Comment: You can get that answer from the treeview documentation. The short answer is that you can put an icon to tne left of each row, but not in a column to the right.